# How can i clicked on the button in location tab?

Tags: android, class, button

I have 2 java class and 2 xml file in layout folder. In location.java class, i setcontentView by location file and location.xml file have 5buttons but in location java class not implemented onClick methods. When i clicked on the buttons in location tab, the program has stopped and i don't know How to solve this problem? Do i implement onClick methods all buttons in Location.java class? I write my code on below:

Please help me

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;
private Button mHome;
private Button mProduct;
private Button mPlaces;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/code/home/home.php");

    mHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_home);
    mProduct=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_product);
    mPlaces=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_places);

    mHome.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    mProduct.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    mPlaces.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

}
private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_home:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/code/home/home.php");
            break;
        case R.id.button_product:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/design/catalog/catalog1.php");
            break;
        case R.id.button_places:
            Intent i=new Intent(Main.this,Location.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
};
}
```

Location.java

```
 public class Location extends MapActivity {
private FrameLayout linear;
private MapView map;
private MapController controller;
private EditText text_location;
double myLatitude;
double myLongitude;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location);
    initMapView();
    initZoomControls();
    initMyLocation();
    //Not complete this method
    text_location.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            // The map should shows a location that user writes in edittex.
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // Required by MapActivity
    return false;
}
private void initMapView() {
    linear = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
    text_location=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_location);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    controller = map.getController();
    map.setSatellite(true);
}
private void initZoomControls() {
    View zoomControls = map.getZoomControls();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL + Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    linear.addView(zoomControls, p);
}
private void initMyLocation() {
    final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
    overlay.enableMyLocation();
    overlay.enableCompass(); // no effect in emulator
    overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Zoom in to current location
            controller.setZoom(8);
            controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });
    map.getOverlays().add(overlay);

    myLatitude=(overlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6())/1e6;
    myLongitude=(overlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6())/1e6;

}
 }
```

Main_Activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_home"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:text="@string/button_home"
        android:textColor="@color/text_home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_product"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/product_icon"
        android:onClick="Product"
        android:text="@string/button_product"
        android:textColor="@color/text_product" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_places"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/places_icon"
        android:onClick="Places"
        android:text="@string/button_places"
        android:textColor="@color/text_places" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_rewards"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/rewards_icon"
        android:onClick="Rewards"
        android:text="@string/button_rewards"
        android:textColor="@color/text_rewards" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_more"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/more_icon"
        android:onClick="More"
        android:text="@string/button_more"
        android:textColor="@color/text_more" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

location.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:apiKey="0cPRv243zM1_S3ydsNg8MJP9_6BfCp642jOhPvQ"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/backgroundTextSearch">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:lines="1"/>    
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_home"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:text="@string/button_home"
        android:textColor="@color/text_home"
    />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_product"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/product_icon"
        android:onClick="Product"
        android:text="@string/button_product"
        android:textColor="@color/text_product" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_home"/>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_places"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/places_icon"
        android:onClick="Places"
        android:text="@string/button_places"
        android:textColor="@color/text_places"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_product" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_rewards"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/rewards_icon"
        android:onClick="Rewards"
        android:text="@string/button_rewards"
        android:textColor="@color/text_rewards" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_places"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_more"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/more_icon"
        android:onClick="More"
        android:text="@string/button_more"
        android:textColor="@color/text_more"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_rewards" />

</RelativeLayout> 
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all `android:onClick` tags from your layout file. It seems you don't really know what they needs for. 
If you set `android:onClick="Product"` tag for your button for example, it meens you must implement such function in your code to handle `onClick` event.

```
@Override
public void Product(){
...
}
```

You absolutely don't need such tags in your layouts if you define `onClick` callbacks in your code.